# How can I intialize a ScrollView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I wanted to make some changes for my ScrollView in Xamarin/Visual Studio, so i gave it a "x:name" in XAML. There is already a ListView with x:name, that is initialized in the .xaml.g.cs file.

And heres my problem: I thought when i give a x:name to a XAML tag it will automatically initialize within InitializeComponent() in the .xaml.g.cs file -maybe after building the project- but: the file wont update AND you can´t modify the .xaml.g.cs file :(

Maybe you can give me a clue, how to initialize a named XAML tag so I can call it in the code behind.

Comment: Have you save the file after you gave it a "x:name" in XAML? Try to  save(ctrl+s) the xaml file and then you can call it in the code behind(.cs file).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

You should not touch  .xaml.g.cs files. These files are generated automatically and their content is not a point of deal.

All you need is .xaml and .cs files. In xaml you define your layout and it will be created automatically for you. All properties you set in xaml will be set up. More precisely, layout will be initialized after `InitializeComponent();` call in a constructor. After that you can refer to the all components in the code.

Sometimes .xaml.g.cs files were not updated. In this case it is recommended:

1) Clean a solution;

2) Manually delete *obj* and *bin* folders (or clean them).

A solution need to be rebuilt after this.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: It's worth noting that rebuilding the Solution (By right clicking on the Solution and clicking 'Rebuild Solution') will automatically clean the Solution (deleting `obj` and `bin` folders) and build you Application